# Why does my AlertView take 3 clicks on cancel button to close?

Tags: objective-c, tableview, uialertview

I implemented a UIAlertView that displays a tableView to make a selection and return to the underlying view controller.

The alert view pops up fine, displays all the data and when I click the cancel button it does not respond, then I click it again and it moves position by quarter of an inch, then when I click it for the third time, the alertView finally disappears.

What would cause this type of behavior?

This is the code:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
if (indexPath == nil){
    NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);
    selectedQuote = [self.quotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"         subject title = %@", selectedQuote.title);

    // NOW PULL UP THE ADD QUOTE MAP CONTROLLER SO THIS QUOTE CAN BE ADDED TO ANOTHER CATEGORY

    if(aqmController == nil)
        aqmController = [[AddQuoteMapController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddQuoteMapController" bundle:nil];

    aqmController.selectedQuote = self.selectedQuote;

    //POP UP SBTableAlert

    SBTableAlert *alert;
    alert   = [[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Categorize this Quote" cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" messageFormat:@""];

    [alert setType:SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct];
    [alert.view addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert.view setTag:0];
    [alert setStyle:SBTableAlertStyleApple];

    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert setDataSource:self];

    [alert show];

}

}

#pragma mark - SBTableAlertDataSource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell;

cell = [[[SBTableAlertCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

Category *cat = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

Subject *sub = [cat.subjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text =sub.title;   
cell.detailTextLabel.text = sub.category_title;

return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

Category *cat = [categories objectAtIndex:section];
return cat.subjects.count;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert {

QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.categories = [appDelegate categories];

return self.categories.count;

}

- (NSString *)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

Category *cat = [categories objectAtIndex:section];
NSString *title = [cat category_title];

return title;
}

#pragma mark - SBTableAlertDelegate

- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Category *cat = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

Subject *sub = [cat.subjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

selectedSubject = sub;
NSLog(@"selectedSubject = %@", selectedSubject.title);

//INSERT INTO QUOTEMAP TABLE

// GET SUBJECT_ID
NSString *stringOfSubjectId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", selectedSubject.subject_id];

NSLog(@"mySubjectId= %@", stringOfSubjectId);

// GET THE NEXT QUOTE_MAP_ID

QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
QuoteMap *qm = [[QuoteMap alloc] init];

NSInteger newQuoteMapId = [appDelegate getNextQuoteMapId];
NSLog(@"quote_map_id= %d   subId = %@   quoteId = %@", newQuoteMapId, stringOfSubjectId, selectedQuote.quote_id);

// INSERT INTO QUOTE_MAP TABLE
NSString *stringOfId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newQuoteMapId];

qm.quote_map_id = stringOfId;
qm.subject_id   = stringOfSubjectId;
qm.quote_id     = selectedQuote.quote_id;
//qm.isDirty      = YES;

[qm insertQuoteMap:qm];

//Add it to the array.
[qmv.quoteMaps addObject:qm];
[qmv.tableView reloadData];

if (tableAlert.type == SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableAlert.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    else
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    [tableAlert.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

//release
[qm autorelease];


}

- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex     {
NSLog(@"Dismissed: %i", buttonIndex);

[tableAlert release];
}

- (void)dealloc{

[qmv release];   
[subjects release];
[categories release]; 
[selectedSubject release];

}
```

Comment: How is _alertView getting set? What is a SBTableAlert? Seems like a lot of relevant code is missing.

Comment: I included where the _alertView is getting set.  The SBTableAlert is described here: [SBTableAlert](https://github.com/blommegard/SBTableAlert/blob/master/README.markdown)

Comment: In handleLongPress, you need to check the gesture recognizer's `state` property because the method will be called multiple times by the recognizer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971237/uialertview-issue-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243812/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688329/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-on-uitableviewcell-double-call, etc.

Comment: Ok can I just say that you are AWESOME.  That was so simple and I could have spent hours on it!  Thank you so much! Not sure how I accept this as an answer but it was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should be using SBTableAlertDatasource and SBTableAlertDelegate methods instead of the UITableViewDatasource and UITableviewDelegate methods.

Also gesture is UILongPressGestureRecognizer. That is a continuous recognizer. You need to check for the state of the recognizer and ignore all the events that come after UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan

Comment: Possibly. Do you have any experience using this SBTableAlert? Everything else works perfectly except this point. The sample provided uses the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegates from what I can tell, so I don't think this is the error.

Comment: I too looked at the sample and it does not use those methods, it uses SBTableAlert datasource and delegate methods.  https://github.com/blommegard/SBTableAlert/blob/master/SBTableAlertDemo/SBTableAlertDemo/RootViewController.m

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  You'll have to excuse my naivety, but the way I was trying to do it was edit the SBTableAlert.m file itself, not use a separate rootViewController. I am going to try and rework it to duplicate the sample better.

Comment: No problem. When using third party classes, you typically never modify the source to implement it. First of all, if the creator updates the code, bug fixes or whatever, all you have to do is download the new code and copy over your existing file. Secondly, if you feel you want to customize the behavior of a class you did not create, you should either subclass or create category methods.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered, if it answered your question. Thanks.

Comment: I corrected my implementation so none of the original classes were modified.  I got the program back to the same point I was at before and it has the same behavior on the alertView.  The original post is being edited to include the modified code.

Comment: It seems like I am invoking multiple instances of the alert view or on separate threads or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Well now that you showed more code, I see what the problem is. You gesture is UILongPressGestureRecognizer. That is a continuous recognizer. You need to check for the state of the recognizer and ignore all the events that come after `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`